# Bar chart labels disappear when PlotRange is used

Tags: plotting, charts

I have used `Placed[Before]` to place labels on the labels before the bars, but when I specify a plot range, the labels disappear. I need a solution wherein I can use `PlotRange` and `Placed[Before]` without the labels disappearing.

Comment: Please edit your post by inserting a image of a plot that shows your problem. Also, include the _Mathematica_ code that produced the plot. This will help others to help you.

Comment: @m_goldberg do they have enough rep for that?

Comment: @cormullion No, but they can give URL to image that someone with higher rep can edit to display inline. Very odd restriction in the first place in my opinion. m_goldberg: I think you needed higher rep :)

Comment: @cormullion. That slipped my mind. If it hadn't, I would have only asked for code.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change setting  of the option `ImagePadding`. With default setting for `ImagePadding`, labels are cut out:

```
 BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[{"label1", "label2", "label3"}, Before], 
    BarOrigin -> Left, Ticks -> None, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, All}]
```

[image]

```
 BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, 
  ChartLabels -> Placed[{"label1", "label2", "label3"}, Before], 
  BarOrigin -> Left, Ticks -> None, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, All}, 
  ImagePadding -> 30]
```

[image]

If you wish, you can pad only the side you need by setting the padding values for other sides to `Automatic`:

```
 BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, 
   ChartLabels -> Placed[{"label1", "label2", "label3"}, Before], 
   BarOrigin -> Left, Ticks -> None, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, All}, 
   ImagePadding -> {{30, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```